# Indirect addressing in Arraylist

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList of TextView type.
I want to set text for each TextView objects in ArrayList,by below code.
How i can do this?

I tried below code.but it is not Correct.
        `txt.set(c,words.get(c));`

```
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("One");
    words.add("Two");
    words.add("Three");
    words.add("Four");
    ArrayList<TextView> txt = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.P1rootView);
    for (int c=0;c<words.size();c++){
        txt.add(c,new TextView(this));
        txt.set(c,words.get(c));
        ll.addView(txt.get(c));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `txt.set(c, words.get(c))` you're trying to put String object in the list of TextViews, which is incorrect of course.

Correct version:

```
txt.get(c).setText(words.get(c));
```

`txt.get()` returns TextView, after that text can be set to the TextView.